# (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for RegisterComponent: (Router, UserService, ?)

Tags: angular, service

the error:**(SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for RegisterComponent:(Router, UserService, ?)**

this is component:RegisterComponent

```
import { Component,OnInit,Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FieldBase } from '../field';
import {UserService} from '../../../core/services/user.service';
import { RegisterService } from '../../../core/services/register.service';

@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'register',
    templateUrl: 'register.component.html',
    styleUrls:['register.component.css'],
})

export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    form:FormGroup;
    registered = false;
    fields:FieldBase<any>[] = [];
    alert:any = {msg:'注册成功',type:'success',closable:true};

    constructor(
        private route:Router,
        private userService:UserService,
        private registerService:RegisterService
        ) {
            this.fields = registerService.getFields();
         }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.form = this.registerService.toFormGroup(this.fields);
    }

    showPassword(){
        this.fields.forEach((field:any)=>{
            if(field.key ==='password'){
                field.type = field.type==='password'?'text':'password';
            }
        });
    }

    resetForm(){
        this.form.reset();
    }

    register(){
        this.registerService.addUser(this.form.value)
            .subscribe(res=>{
                let body = res.json();
                //注册成功
                if(body && body.succes){
                    this.alert.msg = body.message||"注册成功";
                    this.alert.type = body.success?"success":"danger";
                    this.registered = true;
                    this.userService.isLogin = true;
                    //缓存用户信息
                    this.userService.userInfo = {username:this.form.value.username,createDate:new Date().toLocaleDateString()}
                    //跳转到首页
                    this.route.navigate(['']);
                }else{
                    this.registered = false;
                    console.log(body.message);
                }
            },
            (error:any)=>
                console.log(error)
            );
    }
}
```

the RegisterService code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { FormControl,Validators,FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

import { FieldBase,FieldText,FieldValidators} from '../../user/shared/index';
import { SITE_HOST_URL } from '../../shared/index';

@Injectable()
export class RegisterService {

    private registerUrl = `${SITE_HOST_URL}user/add`;

    constructor(private http:Http) { }

    getFields(){
        let fields:FieldBase<any>[]=[
            new FieldText({
                key:'username',
                lable:'用户名',
                value:'',
                required:true,
                pattern:'username',
                order:1
            }),
            new FieldText({
                key:'password',
                lable:'密码',
                type:'password',
                value:'',
                required:true,
                pattern:'password',
                order:2
            }),
        ];
       return fields.sort((a,b)=>a.order - b.order); 
    }

    toFormGroup(fields:FieldBase<any>[]){
        let group :any = {};
        fields.forEach(field=>{
            group[field.key]=
                field.pattern?
                new FormControl(field.value||'',(<any>FieldValidators)[field.pattern]):
                field.required?
                new FormControl(field.value||'',Validators.required):
                new FormControl(field.value||'');
        });
        return new FormGroup(group);
    }

    addUser(data:Object){
        let body = JSON.stringify(data);
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
        return this.http.post(this.registerUrl,body,{headers});
    }
}
```

the CoreModule like this:

```
import { QuestionnaireService } from './services/questionnaire.service';
import { RegisterService } from './services/register.service';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth-guard.service';
import { LoginService } from './services/login.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule,RouterModule],
    exports: [],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [
        QuestionnaireService,
        RegisterService,
        UserService,
        LoginService,
        AuthGuardService]
})
export class CoreModule { 
    constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule :CoreModule){
        if(parentModule){
            throw new Error(
                'CoreModule is already laoded,Import it in the AppModule only'
            );

        }
    }
}
```

spec:other services(QuestionnaireService,UserService..) can run correctly.
if commmenting this param  as below,it will work.

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    form:FormGroup;
    registered = false;
    fields:FieldBase<any>[] = [];
    alert:any = {msg:'注册成功',type:'success',closable:true};

    constructor(
        private route:Router,
        private userService:UserService,
        **//private registerService:RegisterService**
        ) {
            this.fields = registerService.getFields();
         }
```

Comment: Seems like some path is wrong.

Comment: the path of the import statement?

Comment: yes. Please check the paths again. Second, the paths for templates and css files should be from the app folder which is relative to the index.html. Eg: `templateUrl: 'app/register/register.component.html',
    styleUrls:['app/register/register.component.css'],`

Comment: My friend discovery a problem:the service--RegisterService (you can see the resource code);initial the variable without key word "new",this will be OK.look here:

Comment: let fields:FieldBase<any>[]=[
            new FieldText({
                key:'username',
                lable:'用户名',
                value:'',
                required:true,
                pattern:'username',
                order:1
            }),
            new FieldText({
                key:'password',
                lable:'密码',
                type:'password',
                value:'',
                required:true,
                pattern:'password',
                order:2
            })

Comment: I don't know why.

Comment: Hmm.. Strange. Seems like a error trace problem. Did you raise a issue in github about the misleading error?

Comment: yeah,I have published this issue on github,and Nobody reply me .the route  of my code resource in github is https://github.com/dukehq/angular2_demo.you can get it ,if you are interested it.

Comment: ok cool perfect